# jquery ajax send form.serialize, variable and array all as data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have below jquery AJAX,

```
var reply_content = $('#summernote_1').code();

$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/test/send_reply/"+<?php echo $testinfo->test_id;?>,
        data: $("#test_fm").serialize()+'&file=' + file + '&test_subject=<?php echo $testinfo->testsubject;?>' +'&reply_content=' + reply_content,
});
```

i have **file** variable is array contains like below

```
array([0]=> a [1]=>b),
```

This was returned with other function which i am passing in AJAX,

How can i pass this in AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var reply_content = $('#summernote_1').code();

    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/test/send_reply/"+<?php echo $testinfo->test_id;?>,
            data: {$("#test_fm").serialize()+'&file=' + file + '&test_subject=<?php echo $testinfo->testsubject;?>' +'&reply_content=' + reply_content},
    });
```

and you can use `serilizeArray()`

Comment: i tried to put {} in data: but it thrown error on page load,  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: data: {form_data:$("#test_fm").serialize(),file:file},

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying it in php then you can try like this:

```
$url = urlencode(serialize($your_array))
```

append `$url` in the data

```
data: {$("#test_fm").serialize()+"&file=<?php echo $url; ?>&test_subject=<?php echo $testinfo->testsubject;?>" +"&reply_content=" + reply_content}
```

and to restore the variable you can use

```
$arrVar = unserialize(urldecode($_POST['file']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray()` to create an object you can add too.
Its also a good idea to separate your php from you js where possible to aid readability:

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/test/send_reply/' . $testinfo->test_id;?>";

var test_subject = "<?php echo $testinfo->testsubject;?>";

var data = $("#test_fm").serializeArray();

data.push(
    {
        file: file, 
        test_subject: test_subject
    }
);
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
});
```

Comment: data.push is not adding file and test_subject to data array, when i send ajax only test_fm values are gone rest are shown as undefined,